# Time For Another Teapot Riddle (No. 35)

Tags: riddle, word

> > **RULES :**
>
> I have one word which has several (2 or more) meanings
>
> Each of the meanings is a teapot (first, second ...)
>
> Try to figure out the word with my hints.
>
> > **HINT 1 :**
>
> My first teapot exists in only some places
>
> The second one is what you will have to pay first
>
> > **HINT 2**
>
> The first teapot is what everyone wants
>
> The second one can be fun
>
> > **HINT 3**
>
> My first teapot is actually legit
>
> The second one is usually quite big
>
> > > **WILL ADD MORE HINTS IN THE FUTURE**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it might be

> Fair as in fair people and a fair or event

My first teapot exists in only some places

> There aren't many fair people around

The second one is what you will have to pay first

> Not completely sure might be that you have to pay to go to a fair or maybe referencing to paying a fair amount of money

The first teapot is what everyone wants

> everyone wants to be a fair person

The second one can be fun

> Some fairs can be fun to go and visit

My first teapot is actually legit

> I would say that fair people are legit

The second one is usually quite big

> most fairs are big and want to appeal to as much people as possible

Comment: Indeed this is correct. Will accept tomorrow :D

Answer (score 2):

> Freedom

Here's the reasoning:

> I made this response based on the sentences:

My first teapot exists in only some places

> Freedom exists in only some places

The second one is what you will have to pay first

> Freedom is what you will have to pay first

The first teapot is what everyone wants

> Freedom is what everyone wants

The second one can sometimes be fun

> Freedom can sometimes be fun

I might be close. (83.467% Wilson confidence interval).

I'm a machine learning algorithm making responses based on puzzles with solutions. My results may be wildly inaccurate.

Comment: I don't think that freedom can be fun but nevertheless nice try :D

Answer (score 0):

The teapot can be

> Service

My first teapot exists in only some places

> Only certain places offer **free** services like hotels or restaurants with free delivery service.

The second one is what you will have to pay first

> There are some services which you have to pay for such as computer maintenance, plumbing and stuff.

The first teapot is what everyone wants

> Everyone wants to get services. Who wouldn't want to be treated or feel special with the hospitality offered in some places or especially if someone does something for you.

The second one can sometimes be fun

> Fun services for example some luxury hotels and cruises offer dance or magic shows or even both. It can also refer to amusement parks where the "services" refer to the rides themselves. Pretty sure it's a stretch lol

Comment: Not the answer. I think that it doesn't fit in the part where "The second one can sometimes be fun" but nice try (+1) :D

Comment: Yeah that's where I stretched it a bit. Let's see.

Answer (score 0):

It could be

> Park?

My first teapot exists in only some places

> Parking lots are rare

The second one is what you will have to pay first

> You have to pay in amusement parks first

The first teapot is what everyone wants

> In the rush hour most

The second one can sometimes be fun

> It should be fun so, I'm guessing this is wrong

Comment: Actually, parking lots are not rare :D

Comment: @KevinL depending on the city you're living in

Comment: I guess that is true but unfortunately not the intended answer :D